# ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next in java

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am getting `ResultSet` not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next in java error when i try execute following code. Please anyone help me

```
PreparedStatement m_inoutid = null;
 docno="[101,102,103,104]";
 String minoutid[]=new String[1000];
 String documentno = docno.substring(1, docno.length() - 1);
 List<String> docnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
 String[] split = documentno.split(",");
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

  String sql = "select id from mytable where fid=?";

   outid = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   String  idfromquery=split[i];
    outid.setString(1, idfromquery);
    ResultSet idResultSet = outid.executeQuery();
    idResultSet.next();

    id = idResultSet.getString("id");

   final List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
   parameters.add(null);
   parameters.add(id);

   myfunction(parameters);
    }
```

Comment: It is helpful that you included the code, but it would be really good if you showed *the exact text of the error message* (including stack trace). Your code also looks strangely indented. Finally, you really shouldn't be doing SQL in a loop like this - just do a single `SELECT` that finds all 1000 results with an appropriate `WHERE` clause (join on a `VALUES` list or temp table, ...)

Comment: You're not checking the return from `idResultSet.next()`: If the query returns no rows your code will explode.

Answer (score 0):

The code should have looked like this (in Java 7 or higher):

```
String docno = "[101,102,103,104]";
String[] minoutid = new String[1000];
String documentno = docno.substring(1, docno.length() - 1);
String[] split = documentno.split(",");

String sql = "select id from mytable where fid=?";
try (PreparedStatement outid = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        int fid = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        outid.setInt(1, fid);
        try (ResultSet idResultSet = outid.executeQuery()) {
            if (idResultSet.next()) {
                String id = idResultSet.getString("id");
                final List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
                parameters.add(null);
                parameters.add(id);

                myfunction(parameters);
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

This closes prepared statement and result set. Also I have used `setInt` instead of `setString` (maybe erroneously). But that could have given the error, as otherwise everything worked ia a way. Give the error if this does not help.

Comment: Thanks you for your help .. i found where is mistake..I found the problem. When i splitting string by ',' its adding space from second string. I used trim() to elimiate those spances. Now working fine...

Answer (score 0):

From second string a space was added in each string. I am using POSTGREYSQL so each space will take it as string. So i elimiate the space of string by trim().Now working fine. Thank you all